# regarding kubernetes 1.27.2, anybody knows how to solve the kubelet journalctl error of ""Failed updating cpu usage nano core"

Tags: docker, kubernetes

all, i currently deployed kubernetes 1.27.2 on my working networks, the version info is like below:

```
    - CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
    - GO version go1.20.4
      
    - Docker-CE 24.0.2
    - cri-dockerd 0.3.2
      
    - Containerd Containerd.io 1.6.21
      
    - kube-apiserver:v1.27.2
    - kube-controller-manager:v1.27.2
    - kube-scheduler:v1.27.2
    - kube-proxy:v1.27.2
    - pause:3.9/pause:3.6 (pause:3.6 is required for kubectl init procedure, not sure why)
    - etcd:3.5.7-0
    - coredns:v1.10.1
```

On the master node, the journalctl log of kubelet always prompts the error of "Failed updating cpu usage nano core" err="zero or negative interval (1686015180512008450 - 1686041401143535060)", details like below:

```
    Jun 06 09:33:00 controller-master kubelet[945]: E0606 09:33:00.520295     945 cri_stats_provider.go:757] "Failed updating cpu usage nano core" err="zero or negative interval (1686015180512008450 - 1686041401143535060)"
    Jun 06 09:33:00 controller-master kubelet[945]: E0606 09:33:00.520325     945 cri_stats_provider.go:757] "Failed updating cpu usage nano core" err="zero or negative interval (1686015180513632138 - 1686041401144229382)"
    Jun 06 09:33:00 controller-master kubelet[945]: E0606 09:33:00.520355     945 cri_stats_provider.go:757] "Failed updating cpu usage nano core" err="zero or negative interval (1686015180515665184 - 1686041401135390384)"
    Jun 06 09:33:00 controller-master kubelet[945]: E0606 09:33:00.520386     945 cri_stats_provider.go:757] "Failed updating cpu usage nano core" err="zero or negative interval (1686015180517282786 - 1686041401133856169)"
```

is here anybody could help me to solve this problem? thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Can you try restarting your kubelet by running the command `docker restart kubelet`. This will recover your master node.

Comment: @Srividya thanks for your reply. in some extension, the command of "systemctl restart kubelet" works to recover the nano core info update, but it will definitely cause the all "pod restart", and afterwards, some of the pod in kube-system readiness status will fail to update, becomes "0/2, 0/1". i am wondering if here is some effective way to recover: 1. "NANO CORE" info update;  2. POD readiness status info update. thanks.

Comment: There could be multiple factors for the issue one of it is an issue with NTP sync issue. Please check out this [doc](https://slack-archive.rancher.com/t/8544238/kubelet-error-log-failed-updating-cpu-usage-nano-core-cluste).Otherwise there is no non-disruptive way to fix this. You can cordon and drain the node and pod will schedule on other node.